# Mantra/Sloka to chant before we lit a lamp

Tags: shiva, puja, sadhana

For water we usually chant `gange cha` [sloka](https://greenmesg.org/stotras/others/gange_ca_yamune_caiva.php), which provides all auspiciousness of these holy rivers:

- ganga.
- yamuna.
- godhavari.
- saraswati.
- narmada.
- sindhu.
- kaveri.

---

Question:

Is there anything similar before, we lit a lamp?

Comment: Usually " Deepa jyotir parabrahma ..." shloka is recited while lighting lamp .. see this video--- https://youtu.be/CbAllne_Wjs?si=PF-EIGh3PAzo0r5c

Comment: @Rickross thanks for the information, Adding the text link for other seekers.
https://greenmesg.org/stotras/others/shubham_karoti_kalyanam.php

Comment: @Rickross, any idea the source of this shotra. Who composed it?

Comment: No I don't know the source